# onSharedPreferenceChanged isn't called everytime a preference has been changed

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a problem with onSharedPreferenceChanged is only called the first time when a MultiSelectListPreference has changed. I open my settings activity and change the value which works fine and onSharedPreferenceChanged is getting called. If I open the dialog again, it shows the correct entries selected. I select another entry and hit OK. onSharedPreferenceChanged should now getting called but isn't. If I now open the dialog again, no entries are selected. Am I missing something or did I do somethign wrong?

Here's my preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <MultiSelectListPreference
        android:key="operations"
        android:title="@string/pref_operations"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_operations"
        android:entries="@array/pref_operations_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_operations_values"
        android:defaultValue="@array/pref_operations_default" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And my settings fragment

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment 
          implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{    
    public static final String KEY_OPERATIONS_PREFERENCE = "operations";

    private MultiSelectListPreference operationsPreference;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        operationsPreference = (MultiSelectListPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(KEY_OPERATIONS_PREFERENCE);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        Set<String> operations = operationsPreference.getValues();
        String summary = "";
        for (String s : operations)
            summary += s + " ";
        operationsPreference.setSummary(summary);

       sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onPause()
   {
       super.onPause();

       getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
   }

   @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
    {
        if (key.equals(KEY_OPERATIONS_PREFERENCE))
        {            
            Set<String> operations = operationsPreference.getValues();
            String summary = "";
            for (String s : operations)
                summary += s + " ";
            operationsPreference.setSummary(summary);
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm frankly I built my sharedPreferances differently...ill attach my code example and hopefully it'll be of use to you
here goes:

this is the sharedpreferences class

```
public class AppPreferences {
        public static final String KEY_LANG = "language";
        final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = AppPreferences.class.getSimpleName(); // Name
                                                                                // of
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // file
                                                                                // -.xml
        private SharedPreferences _sharedPrefs;
        private Editor _prefsEditor;

        public AppPreferences(Context context) {
            this._sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS,
                    Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            this._prefsEditor = _sharedPrefs.edit();
        }

        public String getlanguage() {
            return _sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_LANG, "");
        }

        public void savelanguage(String text) {
            _prefsEditor.putString(KEY_LANG, text);
            _prefsEditor.commit();
        }
    }
```

to use it youll need to create 
in your class

```
private AppPreferences _appPrefs;
```

and an example for use is

```
    _appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            _appPrefs.savelanguage("English");
language = _appPrefs.getlanguage();
```

this is how i built it... works like a charm... and not complicated at all

Answer (score 0):

It's because you unregister the listener in your onPause callback method which is invoked when Dialog is shown in an Activity.

Comment: Did you try putting a break point in your onSharedPreferenceChanged method from the start and check that ti's being called 1st time and not getting called the 2nd time?

Comment: I did that. It is called the first but not the second time. Other preferences, for example list preferences seem to just work fine if added the same way.